# How would be the xml to satisfy c# condition?

Tags: c#, xml

I am not too much aware of xml.
I got a project having code as follows:

```
XmlNodeList signature = script.GetElementsByTagName("signature", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");

if (signature != null) 
{
  if (signature.Count > 0) 
  {
     return true;
  }
}
return false;
```

I am not able to get the xml code to satisfy the given condition to `return true` from the code.

I have tried so far as but it is incorrect.

```
<signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"> 
test
</signature>
```

Can anyone please let me know how I can create an xml to satisfy the given condition to get the signature `count > 0`?

When I tried with the `script.GetElementsByTagName("signature")` in that case the `count is 1`. So why it is not working with the `GetElementsByTagName(string,string)` method?

And please help me to understand how the function `GetElementsBytagName` works?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Capital S for Signature?

Comment: @LInsoDeTeh I have corrected the code

Comment: Have you debugged it? Is signature null or is the Count 0 ?

Comment: What is `script`? `GetElementsByTagName` gets all *descendants* with that tag name, so if script is pointing at the signature element you're effectively search signature for a signature.

Comment: And does it now work with the corrected code? For me your pasted code returns true without any problems

Comment: What is `script` - how is it defined and initialised? Note that [`GetElementsByTagName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzbctxhh(v=vs.110).aspx) (if `script` is an `XmlDocument`) returns "a list of all **descendant** elements" (My emphasis)

Comment: @Shelby115 `script` is a `XMLdocument` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the comments, if your counter returns 0 and the script object is an XmlDocument then the problem is clearly the LOAD of your xml... 
Check this out, it works for me:

```
var script = new XmlDocument();
        script.LoadXml("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><signature xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\">test</signature>");
        XmlNodeList signature = script.GetElementsByTagName("signature", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");

        if (signature != null)
        {
            if (signature.Count > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
```

Comment: I have tried your code, but still the `signature.Count = 0`. when i tried with the `script.GetElementsByTagName("signature")` the count is 1 with your code.
So why it is not working with the `GetElementsByTagName(string,string)` method.

Comment: If so, then it is clearly a matter of NamespaceUri (the second string).. check how it is spelled on the original xml. It is the one named xmlns on the signature element.

Comment: if you can modify the original xml, try something like this:`script.LoadXml("<signature xmlns=\"lalala\">test</signature>");
            XmlNodeList signature = script.GetElementsByTagName("signature", "lalala");`

Comment: note that the \ (backslash) in the xmlns are just escape characters for the string doublequotes. You must ommit these on your original xml

Comment: yes, there was a problem with the namespace.
a namespace character was capital.
Thanks for the answer and help.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this based on your source code and it works without any problems. Probably your script variable is not initialized correctly?

```
XmlDocument script = new XmlDocument();
script.LoadXml("<signature xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\">test</signature>");

XmlNodeList signature = script.GetElementsByTagName("signature", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.The code is working fine but I am getting the `elements.count = 0` but I want it more than that

Answer (score 1):

I tried it based on your code and it works for me.

```
var script = new XmlDocument();
script.LoadXml("<signature>test</signature>");

var elements = script.GetElementsByTagName("signature");
Console.WriteLine(elements.Count);

for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(elements[i].InnerXml);
}
```

link to [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XsCJJv). Does your script variable hold any elements?

Comment: thanks for the answer.
i am getting count for the elements as 0.
and I need to use the `GetElementsByTabName(string, string)`["https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzbctxhh(v=vs.110).aspx"] method for retrieving the elements.

Answer (score 1):

The getElementsByTagName return the list of xmlNode whose tag name is matched by passed value, For example to get all nodes with tagname test you can use function GetElementsByTagName("test").

You can test against the following xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
      <Document>
        <signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <TestSign></TestSign>
        </signature>
        <signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <TestSign></TestSign>
        </signature>
        <signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <TestSign></TestSign>
        </signature>
    </Document>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But still I am getting the `signature.count =0`. I need it to be more than that.

Comment: The tag name needs to excatly same as your search string for example signature in your case, Please cross check casing of your search